# Is it possible to disable slide animation in the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I navigate between fragments using the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).

As you can see when I press the back button it moves me to the previous fragment but the title and overflow icon is sliding from right to left.

[image]

How can I disable this animation, I don't need any animation. What should I use to disable it?

Please if that is not possible tell me for finding an alternative way instead of waiting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JackTheHealer Unfortunately no, I did not find anyone talking about this issue.